# Hardware load balancer to local public IP not accessible

Tags: networking, router, dns, ip, load-balancer

I have a small network, where I have TP-Link TL-ER5120 load balancer installed for maintaining the internet connection.

Here is how my network looks like:
[image]

The problem:

I have a web server setup at `192.168.1.100` (IP coming from load-balancer) and a public IP on WAN1 to access this.

So I have set up a NAT with a port open on both router 1 and load-balancer with their reference IP address. So I can access the website from public IP address.

Now the problem in whole situation is:

** When I am trying to access the public IP from my local network then I am not able to ping that public IP address.**

So I am guessing there is some routing issue. I didn't touch the router settings, here is how it looks like:

[image]
[image]

**So I am just trying to understand why am I not able to access the public IP from my network? From outside the network web-server is accessible without any problem.**

Any suggestions why this could be happening?

Comment: This class of problem is called "hairpin NAT" It appears your load balancer can't handle this - its common on SOHO routers.  Its generally best and easiest to use DNS or hosts files and have internal servers resolve the 192.168 address for the site.

Comment: @davidgo can you please elaborate this in more derail?

Comment: I really don't want to (hence the comment).  Have a look at https://serverfault.com/questions/55611/loopback-to-forwarded-public-ip-address-from-local-network-hairpin-nat/557776